# Drawing multiple univariate normal distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib, normal-distribution

Does anyone know how to draw multiple Gaussian distributions on a single plot using Python?
Ive got some normal distributed data with different means and standard deviations that i need to plot. Thnx a lot
I could draw only one. Please be simple with me, ive literally just started using Python

Comment: What have you tried and why is it not working? See [mcve]

Comment: i can make a single distribution on a single plot. there are loads of examples which i searched easily online but i want to make multiple normal ditributions on a single plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you have 3 different combinations of mean `mu` and standard deviaton `sigma`. You can choose as many as you like, but for example purposes I used 3.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as mp
import numpy as np

def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return 1./(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma)*np.exp(-0.5 * (1./sigma*(x - mu))**2)

for mu, sig in [(0.5, 0.1), (1.0, 0.2), (1.5, 0.3)]: #(mu,sigma)
    mp.plot(gaussian(np.linspace(-8, 8, 100), mu, sig))

mp.show()
```

Define your `mu` and `sigma` in this line, you can add as many combinations as you like:

```
for mu, sig in [(0.5, 0.1), (1.0, 0.2), (1.5, 0.3)]: #(mu,sigma)
```

in my case it is

- mu = 0.5, sigma = 0.1
- mu = 1.0, sigma = 0.2
- mu = 1.5, sigma = 0.3

**Result**:

[image]

***EDIT**

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as mp
import numpy as np

def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return 1./(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma)*np.exp(-0.5 * (1./sigma*(x - mu))**2)

for mu, sigma in [(1, 2), (0.5, 1), (0, 0.5)]: #(mu,sigma)
    mp.plot(gaussian(np.linspace(-4, 6, 100, ), mu, sigma))
    mp.xlim(0,110)  #set x-axes limits
    mp.ylim(0,1)  #set y-axes limits

mp.show()
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: just a note, if you have data and need to calculate mean and stdev you can use  `scipy.stats.norm` package to calculate those

Comment: `np.linespace` returns evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval, for more info check https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

If this answers your question, you can accept it as an answer by checking colored checkmark next to the answer, so that others who have similar problem can try this solution. Thank you

Comment: thnx man this is what i need. question though, mp.plot(gaussian(np.linspace(-8, 8, 100), mu, sig)) the 100 is the domain range right? but what about the -8 and 8? thnx again man

Comment: 100 is number of samples

Comment: oh so -8 to 8 is the interval and 100 is the number of samples right? but interval of the curve generated is between 0 to 100. i dont get it

Comment: you are probably confusing it with `xlim`, try to add `mp.xlim(-8,8)` after function and see what you get. With `linespace` you are just generating samples in interval.

Comment: oh i undertand about the intervals but how do you change the number of the absis axis (i think this is whats it called) because in your example mu is 0.5 but on the plot its 50. how can u change the value to be 0.5 and not 50?

Comment: `linespace (-8,8,100)` generates array of 100 numbers with value between -8 and 8, `mu` is mean or expectation of distribution, while `sigma` is the standard deviation. On the x axis is percentage and y axis is f(x) (distribution function). I suppose you want to plot exact values, e.g. when you say that `mu = 0`, peak should be in `x=0`? I can rewrite my answer if you need that

Answer (score 3):

There's a slight issue with the solution proposed by @dejanmarich. The values on the x-axis do not correspond to actual values from the data distribution. To remedy this issue we should not generate an arbitrary linearly spaced range.

Rather we would like to have a plot with x ranging from a lower bound to an upper bound in such a way that the mean is situated in the middle. The following code snippet achieves this goal:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Gaussian:
  @staticmethod
  def plot(mean, std, lower_bound=None, upper_bound=None, resolution=None,
    title=None, x_label=None, y_label=None, legend_label=None, legend_location="best"):
    
    lower_bound = ( mean - 4*std ) if lower_bound is None else lower_bound
    upper_bound = ( mean + 4*std ) if upper_bound is None else upper_bound
    resolution  = 100
    
    title        = title        or "Gaussian Distribution"
    x_label      = x_label      or "x"
    y_label      = y_label      or "N(x|μ,σ)"
    legend_label = legend_label or "μ={}, σ={}".format(mean, std)
    
    X = np.linspace(lower_bound, upper_bound, resolution)
    dist_X = Gaussian._distribution(X, mean, std)
    
    plt.title(title)
    
    plt.plot(X, dist_X, label=legend_label)
    
    plt.xlabel(x_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_label)
    plt.legend(loc=legend_location)
    
    return plt
  
  @staticmethod
  def _distribution(X, mean, std):
    return 1./(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*std)*np.exp(-0.5 * (1./std*(X - mean))**2)
```

Once the class is defined, we may plot a Gaussian distribution in the following way:

```py
Gaussian.plot(0.5, 1).show()

# Or, for multiple plots:

plot = Gaussian.plot(1, 2)
plot = Gaussian.plot(0.5, 1)
plot = Gaussian.plot(0, 0.5)
plot.show()
```

[image]

Here we either define or compute the bounding x range. Computation uses the mean and 4 times the standard deviation in order to center the plot.

This is a very simple class, which can be extended upon in order to fix some issues. 1) Unless multiple plots are drawn we (seem to) look at the same drawing, and 2) tails are cut off when plotting multiple distributions.

1) Is easily fixed by adding `plt.ylim(0,1)` to the `plot` method. 2) On the other hand, requires us to take into account the shape of all plots while drawing.

To do this, we may change our class into a [builder class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). We first aggregate all plot information and only compute the x range when we are ready to draw all the plots.

The following class achieves this goal:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class GaussianPlot:
  def __init__(self, title="Gaussian Distribution", x_label="x", y_label=None,
    y_limit=None, lower_bound=None, upper_bound=None, 
    with_grid=True, fill_below=True, legend_location="best"):
    
    self.title           = title
    self.x_label         = x_label
    self.y_label         = y_label or "N({}|μ,σ)".format(x_label)
    self.y_limit         = y_limit
    self.lower_bound     = lower_bound
    self.upper_bound     = upper_bound
    self.with_grid       = with_grid
    self.fill_below      = fill_below
    self.legend_location = legend_location
    
    self.plots = []
  
  def plot(self, mean, std, resolution=None, legend_label=None):
    self.plots.append({
      "mean":         mean,
      "std":          std,
      "resolution":   resolution,
      "legend_label": legend_label
    })
    
    return self
  
  def show(self):
    self._prepare_figure()
    self._draw_plots()
    
    plt.legend(loc=self.legend_location)
    plt.show()
  
  def _prepare_figure(self):
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(self.title)
    
    plt.xlabel(self.x_label)
    plt.ylabel(self.y_label)
    
    if self.y_limit is not None:
      plt.ylim(0, self.y_limit)
    
    if self.with_grid: 
      plt.grid()
  
  def _draw_plots(self):
    lower_bound = self.lower_bound if self.lower_bound is not None else self._compute_lower_bound()
    upper_bound = self.upper_bound if self.upper_bound is not None else self._compute_upper_bound()
    
    for plot_data in self.plots:
      mean         = plot_data["mean"]
      std          = plot_data["std"]
      resolution   = plot_data["resolution"]
      legend_label = plot_data["legend_label"]
      
      self._draw_plot(lower_bound, upper_bound, mean, std, resolution, legend_label)
  
  def _draw_plot(self, lower_bound, upper_bound, mean, std, resolution, legend_label):
    resolution   = resolution or max(100, int(upper_bound - lower_bound)*10)
    legend_label = legend_label or "μ={}, σ={}".format(mean, std)
    
    X = np.linspace(lower_bound, upper_bound, resolution)
    dist_X = self._distribution(X, mean, std)
    
    if self.fill_below: plt.fill_between(X, dist_X, alpha=0.1)
    plt.plot(X, dist_X, label=legend_label)
  
  def _compute_lower_bound(self):
    return np.min([plot["mean"] - 4*plot["std"] for plot in self.plots])
  
  def _compute_upper_bound(self):
    return np.max([plot["mean"] + 4*plot["std"] for plot in self.plots])
  
  def _distribution(self, X, mean, std):
    return 1./(np.sqrt(2.*np.pi)*std)*np.exp(-np.power((X - mean)/std, 2.)/2)
```

The class is used slightly differently compared to its more simple predecessor:

```py
gaussian_plot = GaussianPlot()\
  .plot(1, 2)\
  .plot(0.5, 1)\
  .plot(0, 0.5)

gaussian_plot.show()
```

[image]

Have a look at the various parameters of `__init__` and `plot` to customize the look and feel of the plot figure. Also note that the resolution of each individual plot may be changed in cases where the Gaussian is not smooth enough.

For instance, the distibution `(μ=0, σ=0.5)` in the plot above could benefit from having a higher resolution:

```py
gaussian_plot = GaussianPlot()\
  .plot(1, 2)\
  .plot(0.5, 1)\
  .plot(0, 0.5, resolution=400)

gaussian_plot.show()
```

Comment: Beautiful solution.  Thanks!